OBS Studio recording timer on the screen during the recording
Is it possible to show the recording time during the recording in OBS studio? My goal is to see the timer on all the windows I open during the recording; If the timer is visible or not on the recorded video (the file generated by obs), it's not important.
So far I used python scripts that only allow to see the timer on the recorded video, but not in real time during the recording.

EDIT: trials with upstream X



Are you recording or streaming? Is another way to explain what you want that you would like a timer visible on your desktop that is being recorded? Just look for a timer app, or use the clock/timer app built in to the computer you're using. I believe every OS has a built in timer app, and there's a plethora of other apps that may have better theming/skinning options.

Do you want to see the timer on the recording itself or not? This question is asked in a very unclear way, I only understood that you want it to start with the recording.

@music2myear yes, I need I timer visible on every windows I open. I prefer to avoid other apps, tools because I'd like the timer starts exactly when I press start recording.

@Destroy666 the important thing is that the timer is visible during the recording. If it is visible also on the recording itself, it's the same for me.

You should edit the question to include additional details. It's also not the same - timer appearing on top of all windows is entirely different than timer on recording.

You can script the startup of OBS https://obsproject.com/kb/launch-parameters, which means that you can call it as part of a longer command which would open another application or utility at the same time. OBS itself might have a setting allows you to trigger an external application when you begin recording as well. Something like AutoHotKey can probably also work to trigger recording in OBS after the program is already running, which might work better for your workflow.

@music2myear thank you for your useful suggestion!

Bunch of ways to achieve it. This one uses several parts:

Add Upstream X script to your OBS, then set it up to only fire when recording and display on chosen text source.

Add Source Dock plugin to OBS. Include the text source above in its settings. Then make it Visible.

Use e.g. PowerToys Always On Top utility to bring the visible docked window on top of other windows.


Another one could involve some CLI tool for a timer + Advanced Scene Switcher plugin that is configured to use Run action to fire the timer whenever the Recording started condition is met. I have only found countdown timers with good CLI documentation, though, no uptime ones.

I tried Upstream X script. It shows the counter only on top of the recorded video, but I cannot see it during the recording (this is my goal).

You didn't follow all the instructions...

can you help me to get my configuration error please? I uploaded images in the edit section.

I have no idea what those screenshots mean. I don't see anything related to Source Dock or the next step.

is it possible to reset the counter automatically when I stop the recording?

It might be possible with Advanced Scene Switcher, recording condition and modifying the timer source's settings as action.
